# Is Identity reset necessary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to copy the data of all tables from one DB to other using `Insert...select` statement.

```
Insert into collist select collist from table
```

I am doing the following things

1. Cleanup of all tables either truncate or delete.
2. Copy data from source to destination (by doing identity_insert on).

After doing this process, do we need to reset the identity again after copying data to my target db?

Comment: It's unclear to me, what is your actual problem then?

Comment: I copied data from one db to other using insert select. It has some identity columns. I want to know whether I have to reset the identity after copying the data to my target db.

Comment: The OP's asking if he/she should reset the `IDENTITY`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Exactly, You are right. Please post your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to reset your `IDENTITY` column. Resetting your `IDENTITY` column might lead to constraint violations. Let's say your `IDENTITY` column is your `PK`.

```
CREATE TABLE aa(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    x INT
)
INSERT INTO aa(x) VALUES (1), (2);
```

Your data looks like this now:

```
id          x
----------- -----------
1           1
2           2
```

Then, you reset the `IDENTITY`:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('aa', RESEED, 0)
```

When you insert new rows into your table, a PK violation error would occur:

```
INSERT INTO aa(x) VALUES (3), (4);
```

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 8 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__aa__3213E83F76F5681B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.aa'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Aaron Bertrand has great insight on resetting `IDENTITY` column. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/reset-identity-value) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the column configuration. If you dont have primary key and unique key constraint on identity column, you can reset identity. But, that would lead to duplication values.

If you dont reset, next record will be inserted with `(maxvalue of column in identity column)+1` as identity value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the data point of view, Identity values should be meaningless.
Meaning that the value of an identity column should not be a part of the data, but only a row identifier.

They are very useful when you have lookup tables (id, name) or data tables where the row uniqueness is comprised of multiple columns and you need to use these tables in a relationship - having an identity column as a surrogate key in these situations can save both you and your database a lot of work.

specifying a column as an identity guarantee almost anything - not even uniqueness - since you can use `SET IDENTITY INSERT tableName ON` and manually insert whatever value you want, even duplicated values (unless there is a unique constraint or index on that column, of course).

Identity is simply a mechanism the database provides to simplify relationships and surrogate keys handling.

That being said, you really should not reset identity values.